# How can i jump to game development and continue career in 7 months?

Tags: game-industry, career, interview

How can i jump to game development and continue career in 7 months?

Comment: 7 months is not that much, i daubt you're going to learn what you have to in this amount of time. You'd probably want to spend half of that getting better at just english if you want to move to the US, where you are now is not going to cut it. If you want a job as a game developer, the most important thing is that you make games. If you have a C# background then you could either try making something with XNA or move to Java and try developing something for the Android. Also C++ is hard to master and games require you to master it. You can't assume you're "just going to learn it".

Comment: Maybe its better not to be fixed to a career as game developer. Why don't you try to get indie? Program games in your spare time. When they're good enough you'll find someone who makes neat graphics for them. Therefore you don't need to live in a extreme wealthy country to do this.

Comment: This question does not have a *correct* answer. GDSE isn't for discussion based questions. I think you knew that before posting it since you say that people can give you downvotes as long as you get answer.

Comment: @DonCarleone Please see the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette) about etiquette. Thanks and good luck with your career, your people skills will come in handy!

Comment: @DonCarleone What makes you think I down voted the answer? It has two down votes, one person can't down vote twice. You don't know who down voted, so don't attack me (or anyone else). People down vote an answer if it's not useful. I imagine down voting this answer would be because it's impossible to answer your question correctly, so pretty much any answer to it is not useful. It's not a personal thing, please, calm down and don't take these things personally. Please practice good etiquette or don't post.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to switch your career to game development you should get some experience on actually making games. I don't believe any company would hire a game programmer without any game programming experience even as a junior.

This may sound hard. How can you get the experience if you can't get a job in the industry? You should start by programming games on your free time or by studying game development in a school. There is also the possibility of starting as an independent game developer, but it doesn't pay you any salary until you succeed.